NiMH Battery Pack, lowest cell in pack dies
I've built several NiMH packs and for some reason, the lowest cell in each pack dies in storage. I recharge them once per month when in storage, and do a forming charge once every 3 months, but I keep getting a 0V cell at the bottom of the stack. I've got 5 packs like this. Pack is 2p18s. I thought it might be an impedance mismatch, but it only happens at the bottom of the pack. What causes this to happen?

Is there anything connected to them, like a battery management system, while in storage?

If you physically placed one upside down is it still the same cell that fails?

@SimonFinch, it has a BMS that draws 13uA from the stack. Bottom cell dies in about 3 weeks of storage.

@Andyaka I hope your question is rhetorical.
